# Как периодически выполнять PHP-функцию после загрузки страницы?

Tags: php, css

Есть страница, на которой нужно менять через CSS изображение в зависимости от того, идёт эфир на определённом ShoutCast-сервере или не идёт. Чтобы делать это, файл style.css превращён в style.php, и начинается он так:

```html
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$ip = "69.197.169.178";
$port = "34622";
$fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1);
if (!$fp) { 
 $status = "offline";
} else { 
 fputs($fp, "GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");
 while (!feof($fp)) {
  $info = fgets($fp);
 }
 $split = explode(',', $info);
 if ($split[1] == "0") {
  $status = "offline";
 } else {
  $status = "online";
 }
}

// Дальше определяются зависимости в CSS от того, $offline или $online.

?>
```

Можно ли выполнять эту функцию через равные промежутки времени *после* загрузки страницы, чтоб CSS был динамическим? Как?

Comment: Держать скрипт в рабочем состоянии через бесконечный цикл с задержкой. Или, я вас советую перенести логику на JS

Comment: Еще хотел добавить, что скрипты php долго не могут работать. У них задача простая, обработать данные и отдать пользователю. А долгое выполнение выдаст ошибку, и сам хостинг вам не даст такую возможность, а значит логику нужно переносить на сторону пользователя.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke